# How to record mouse click and release coordinates in ArcMap using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, click, mouse, coordinates, arcmap

first time poster here. I've been searching for a long time for the answers specific to this but I'm having no luck.

I'm writing a tool in VB.NET that records the bounding coordinates of a rectangle drawn anywhere on the map interface in ArcMap. I need to record the 'mousedown' click coordinates in addition to the 'mouseup' release coordinates.

I've done the same thing in mapinfo using mapbasic which was the simplest thing EVER:

```
' xy where user clicked 
x1 = CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_X)
y1 = CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_y)

' xy where user released
x2 = CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_X2)
y2 = CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_y2)

' check and apply correct ordering of max/min x/y values
if x1 > x2 then
    maxX = x1
    minX = x2
else
    maxX = x2
    minX = x1
end if

if y1 > y2 then
    maxY = y1
    minY = y2
else
    minY = y2
    maxY = y1
end if
```

Now unfortunately I can't seem to do it this simply in VB.NET. I get the impression I need to create a bunch of subs/classes and use events in order to execute this correctly, but I don't know where to start. Can anyone help me? Keep in mind I need to be able to do this anywhere on the map interface (i.e. not within a form/picturebox etc...). I'm using visual studio 2012.

Thanks

-L

Comment: ESRI has tools akin to MapBasic, which is part of MapInfo a totally different product. You would need to use the tools that are displaying the map. I don't think VB.Net is one of the ESRI programming tools, but I could be wrong. I think they retired their MapObjects support. FYI there are some ESRI tags available with StackOverflow.

Comment: The entire arcmap extension we have developed is written in vb.net using arcobjects and COM. I'm a newbie to the team though so my knowledge of using vb.net is limited. I'll have a look at ways I can trigger tools already present in arcmap. If anyone has any insight on this let me know...

Comment: Marvelous - do you know if anything beyond a desktop ArcGIS license is required (if that?)

Comment: I believe we're all using basic arcgis desktop licenses for development. Our environment is visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using arcObjects, try using the RubberRectagularPolygon class found in the IRubberBand interface:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000002q5000000

It has a RubberRectangular CoClass that has a function that tracks the mouse pointer called "TrackNew" and produces an IGeometry